# Dotnetnuke 3.0.12 installing site "Could not load type 'dotnetnuke.common.global'"

Tags: parsing, dotnetnuke

I received a dotnetnuke 3.0.12 installation in a zip file and made a web site under c:\inetpub\wwwroot and copied the files.

When I access default.aspx, I get the error:

Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.Common.Global'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing an assembly, if the installation has the source files, try loading up the project in Visual studio and step-in to the code.

Comment: Was missing the BIN folder - didn't copy over correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup file permissions for the directory?  Make sure the IIS account (NETWORK SERVICE on Vista/Win 2k3, machine-name\ASPNET on XP/Win 2k) has modify permission on the website (in this case, double-checking the bin folder).